# Material UI pagination formatting issue

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I am using material UI table pagination and facing the below issue.
The per-page options should look like this
[image]

However, it is broken and looks like this

[image]

Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you please paste your tablepagination props here

Answer (score 0):

Have you rewritten your rowsPerPage field?

This is the way i use the TablePagination API

```
<TablePagination
  rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 15, 20]}
  component="div"
  count={items.length}
  rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
  page={page}
  onChangePage={(e, page) => setPage(page)}
  onChangeRowsPerPage={(e) => setRowsPerPage(parseInt(e.target.value, 10))}
 />
```

This looks like the first picture, I think some kind of vari

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code it is a bit complicated to find the problem but you can find several examples of implementations of tables in the documentation of material-ui at this URL: https://material-ui.com/components/tables/

There is one called Sorting & selecting that seems to be what you are looking for: (https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#sorting-amp-selecting)

and you can find an example of the full implementation just as you want it on codesandbox right here: https://codesandbox.io/s/f71wj?file=/demo.js